# First mouseclick registered on the parent form when new form is launched through the Tabstrip_Click event

Tags: vb6

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Tabstrip1_Click()
   Form2.Show vbModal, Me
end sub
```

Form2 has just a Close button. The first mouseclick on Form2 has no visible effect unless form2 lies over the calling form, then an error is raised that a modal form cannot be shown twice! So what happens is that the first mouseclick is registered on the parent form. I tried all kind of workarounds (mostly by going through Tabstrip1_GotFocus), but I could not get it to work without doing some very convoluted things.

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to fix mouse capture issues TabStrip control exhibits in your particular case

```
Private Declare Function ReleaseCapture Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Sub TabStrip1_Click()
    Call ReleaseCapture
    Form2.Show vbModal, Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262441 .

As said there, TabStrip (supposedly only the version included in Mscomctl.ocx SP3) does not release the mouse capture, so you have to call [`ReleaseCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261.aspx) before displaying a modal form.

---

aside:

I'd have just edited the previous correct answer but the edit was refused.

*"Introduces an external dependency"* ??? Authoritative references are not a bad thing in my experience, I think the link is going to be useful to someone.